# PHP - An external Class/library is accessible from apache but not from phpunit

Tags: php, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ socket library in my web application. I have configured php.ini so Apache can use ZMQ but I dont know how phpunit can use it.

Dont phpunit use the same php.ini which apache uses?

In phpunit I get following error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZMQContext' not found in /home/idlecool/checker/testcases/checkerTest.php on line 53`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which `php.ini` file is used for Apache and command-line generally depends on your Linux distribution ; if using Debian or Ubuntu, you'll generally have :

- `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` for Apache
- and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for command-line -- and PHPUnit runs as a command-line application.

But note that quite often *(it's true on Ubuntu, by default)*, all `.ini` files from the `/etc/php5/conf.d/` directory will be loaded in both Apache and CLI modes.

Which means that, if you want an extension to be loaded in both modes, you should create a `.ini` file in that directory, loading and configuring it.

For example, you could have a `/etc/php5/conf.d/zmq.ini` file, containing something like :

```
extension=zmq.so
```

*(of course, you'll have to put the name of the right `.so` file)*

Comment: and do not forget /etc/init.d/httpd reload!

Comment: @pascal Martin I am getting the same error on wamp server how to configure this in wamp server?

Comment: What can be the solution in Mac OSX Lion?