# Fatal error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found ( but it is installed and works on the terminal )

Tags: php, nginx

I want to try the ZeroMQ, and I write two php file, service.php and client.php.
I use the linux terminal to run service `php /web/test/service.php`,it's ok, terminal print a "waiting for client connecting...".

but, I request my client.php through chrome explorer,error happened, I check my error.log,there is message "php fatal error: class 'ZMQContext' not found........"

and I use command `php -m` to check my php extension, `zmq` is already in that list.

Comment: If your using windows, remove php as service and run it as admin, worked for me

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the ZMQ module is loaded in the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) but it's not loaded into Apache. Therefore, `service.php` runs smoothly from the Command Line but `client.php` can't use ZMQContext because Apache does not load ZMQ.

There are two different `.ini`-files. These probably are (but can be different, depending on your distro):

- `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` for Apache
- `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for CLI

However, all `.ini` files from the `/etc/php5/conf.d/` directory are loaded into both Apache and the CLI.

See also: [PHP - An external Class/library is accessible from apache but not from phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241231/130580) (the exact opposite of your problem)

Comment: First at all, Thank u,but,I run the `phpinfo()` function, that show me the php.ini is only one placed at /etc/php.ini.

Comment: and I am a fish on Linux server, the server is configured by my teacher,actually,I don't know these config. But I know there are Nginx and PHP.

Comment: When you say you run the `phpinfo()` function, I assume you did that in the cli. This environment differs from the one that's used to deliver webpages trough either Apache or Nginx. Please create a new file (e.g. `info.php`), put `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in it and load the page in your webbrowser in order to see at what location the `.ini` is stored that configurates the web-php.

Answer (score 4):

### Check which php.ini files are loaded

Checking (with `phpinfo`) which php.ini files are loaded when requested via nginx (which probably means via php-fpm) - will almost certainly reveal that it loads different ini files than the cli. Assuming php-fpm usage, the following ini files are probably loaded:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/*
```

and no zmq.ini file listed.

### Loading zmq for php-fpm

Follow the [instructions for installing zmq on php](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php), and create an ini file for zeromq (or copy the one from `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/` since evidently it's loaded for cli usage):

```
# /etc/php5/conf.d/zeromq.ini
extension=zmq.so
```

Then restart php-fpm

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

And zeromq should be available for use.

Comment: I use command `whereis php-fpm`,and it shows `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm` and `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf` .

Comment: I try `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm restart` but,it give me a help manual,like `-n No php,ini file will be used , -i PHP information ....`

Comment: use phpinfo (via a web request) if you are unsure how nginx has been configured - ordinarily it's configured using php-fpm. Or just look at the nginx config files.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way to solve this issue is to enable ZMQ globally (cli + Apache) with phpenmod

For example with php5

```
php5enmod zmq
service apache2 restart
```